# How can I access variables in model declare in a controller?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

This is the controller I have and I want to move currencyCheck to a model or separate utility.js file which I can load in controller but issue is the global variable. I dont know how I can move functions using global variable to a separate js file. Is there a way to declare global variables in UI5?

```
sap.ui.define([
    'jquery.sap.global',
    'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
    'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel',
    'sap/ui/model/Filter',
    'sap/ui/model/FilterOperator',
    'sap/m/MessageToast'
],

function(jQuery, Controller, JSONModel, Filter, FilterOperator, MessageToast) {
    "use strict";

    var price;
    var mainController = Controller.extend("pricingTool.controller.Main", {


        //define global variables
        globalEnv: function() {
            nsnButton = this.byId("nsnButton");
            price = this.byId("price");
        },

        onInit: function(oEvent) {

            //moving this code to Component.js
            //define named/default model(s)
            var inputModel = new JSONModel("model/inputs.json");
            var productsModel = new JSONModel("model/products.json");

            //set model(s) to current xml view
            this.getView().setModel(inputModel, "inputModel");
            this.getView().setModel(productsModel);

            //default application settings
            //unload global variables
            this.globalEnv();
        },

        currencyCheck: function(oEvent) {
            var inputVal = oEvent.getParameters().value;
            var detailId = oEvent.getParameters().id;
            var id = detailId.replace(/\__xmlview0--\b/, "");
            var currencyCode;
            var inputArr = inputVal.split("");

            currencyCode = inputArr[0] + inputArr[1] + inputArr[2];

            if (id === "price") {

                if (inputArr[0].match(/^[\d$]+$/) || currencyCode === 'USD') {
                    price.setValueState("None");
                } else price.setValueState("Error");


            } else if (id === "unitPrice") {
                console.log(inputVal);
                if (inputArr[0].match(/^[\d$]+$/) || currencyCode === 'USD') {
                    unitPrice.setValueState("None");
                } else unitPrice.setValueState("Error");
            }


        },

        onNsnChange: function() {
            //enable "Search" button if input has an entry
            searchQuery = nsnSearchInput.getValue();

            if (searchQuery === "") {
                nsnButton.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                nsnSearchInput.setValueState("None");
                nsnButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        },


    });

    return mainController;
});
```

Comment: Do not use such global variables! Why do you need them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about not using a global variable? You can make your variables local and pass them as a parameter to any other methods even in other classes.

In your `utility.js` define your transferred method as follows:

```
currencyCheck: function (oEvent, price) {
    ...
    // the code from the original function
    ...
}
```

Then you can do the following in your MainController:

```
currencyCheck: function (oEvent) {
    var oPrice = this.byId("price");
    Utility.currencyCheck(oEvent, oPrice);
}
```

Of course you have to import your utility class at the beginning of your controller file.